# How can I get the foreach to work in my code

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-ise

I am trying to get multiple files to input into the `Invoke-WebRequest` one by one and write succuess or failure depending if it works or not.

```
Param(
    [string]$path,
    [string]$file,
    [string]$spath
)
cls

$URI = "Link Can't be shown."

$path = "C:\Users\lfouche.ESSENCEHEALTH\Desktop\Monitoring Services and Sites\"
$spath = "C:\Users\lfouche.ESSENCEHEALTH\Desktop\txtFiles\"

$file = (Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\lfouche.ESSENCEHEALTH\Desktop\Monitoring Services and Sites')

$inF = "$path" + "$file" + ".txt"
$otF = "$spath" + "$file"

foreach ($f in $file) {
    wget $URI -Method post -ContentType "text/xml" -InFile $inF -OutFile $otF
}

if ($? -eq 'true') {
    "Successful"
} else {
    "Failure"
    $LASTEXITCODE 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-ErrorAction Stop` to turn errors into terminating errors and catch them in a `try`/`catch` block.

```
$path  = 'C:\Users\lfouche.ESSENCEHEALTH\Desktop\Monitoring Services and Sites'
$spath = 'C:\Users\lfouche.ESSENCEHEALTH\Desktop\txtFiles'

Get-ChildItem $path | ForEach-Object {
    $file = $_.Name
    $inF  = Join-Path $path "$file.txt"
    $otF  = Join-Path $spath $file
    try {
        Invoke-WebRequest $URI -Method post -ContentType "text/xml" -InFile $inF -OutFile $otF -ErrorAction Stop
        "Success: $file"
    } catch {
        "Failure: $file"
        $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
```

I would also recommend using a `ForEach-Object` loop instead of a `foreach` loop (see sample code above), so you can further process the output with a continued pipeline.

Comment: I have tested this variation of my script with your changes and now $file variable has stored various txt files for what ever reason and i can't figure out why or how it is picking up these no existent files

Comment: @LeandreFouche I don't follow. What do you mean by "has stored various txt files"? The `ForEach-Object` loop iterates over the files produced by `Get-ChildItem`. With each iteration `$file` contains the current filename.

Comment: It cleared up, i don't know why it was picking up different text files that weren't included in the location of the files

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines, although I can't really test it.

```
Param(
    [string]$path,
    [string]$file,
    [string]$spath
)

$URI = "Link Can't be shown."

$path = "C:\Users\lfouche.ESSENCEHEALTH\Desktop\Monitoring Services and Sites\"
$spath = "C:\Users\lfouche.ESSENCEHEALTH\Desktop\txtFiles\"

$files = (Get-ChildItem $path)

foreach ($f in $files) {
    wget $URI -Method post -ContentType "text/xml" -InFile $f.FullName -OutFile $spath + $f.Name
}

if ($? -eq 'true') {
    "Successful"
} else {
    "Failure"
    $LASTEXITCODE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Be careful about using a variable named `$path` in PowerShell. I would avoid it.
2. If you want to test whether the `Invoke-WebRequest` (wget) cmdlet reported errors, use the `-ErrorVariable` parameter to store any error and then check if it's null afterwards. Something like:

   ```
   Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://blabla" -ErrorVariable myerror
   if ($myerror -ne $null) {throw "there was an error"}
   ```

Comment: Nothing wrong with using a variable `$path` in PowerShell. There is no [automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) with that name, and it also can't be confused with the PATH environment variable, since the latter would be `$env:Path`.